Can I move my custom email names from GoDaddy to Azure to save money?
I have a domain name (ex. www.mysite.com) that I purchased from Godaddy.com and I pay a yearly fee. I also purchased 4 email accounts (Microsoft 365) for my domain, but Godaddy.com charges me $8.00/month for each email.
I want to add more emails but don't want to set up and pay for each one, especially not $8.00/month.
What's the best solution?
Doesn't Azure have a way to handle lots of email accounts for my domain, without charging me for each and every one? What do large companies do with hundreds and even thousands of email accounts?
What is Exchange Online?

Are you paying Godaddy AND Microsoft, or are you paying Godaddy to provision Microsoft accounts for you?   If you are paying both Godaddy AND Microsoft for email something is wrong there.   You should investigate a "catch all" account.  If you don't need bells, whistles and support you can look to a provider that offers their own hosting - I think CPANEL hosting (provided by lots of companies) provides this at no additional cost - but it is not as powerful as Microsoft hosting.

@davidgo no I'm not paying Microsoft, just Godaddy. I pay Godaddy for the domain name and for each of the 3 email accounts that give me the domain name in the email address. I just thought there was an easier, cheaper way than buying each email account individually? Can't I set up an MS Exchange server in Azure or something and create unlimited email names from that? What do companies do that need hundreds and even thousands of email accounts? When you say Microsoft hosting, are you talking about Azure?

Cheaper yes. Easier not really.  You can absolutely set up and manage  your own mail server "in the Cloud".  Running a decent  mail server is not a trivial undertaking - and yes - companies whith thousands of accounts often buy them per account from Microsoft or Google as the cost is a rounding error in terms of staffing costs - and means you dont need IT specialists to manage it....

By Microsoft hosting im talking about ibdividual mail boxes fron Microsoft. If you want a budget solution look at CPanel hosting. Dont expect the same level of deliverability or spm handling as provided by large players though.

I don't need hundreds or even thousands but a block of say, 20-30 would be nice! Or even 5-10. Godaddy didn't seem to have any options for this, they only allow me  to purchase each individual account separately.

You have a number of options.

Find a better plan or a better host. I get 500 emails per domain from my host.
Redirect your email to another host
Grab all the email at domain level and use your own server on your machine.



Who is your host? 2. What do you mean redirect your email to another host? 3. Can this be done in Azure? That's what I'm using to host my site.

